# tf.placeholder vs tf.constant

Tags: graph, tensorflow

I have a fundamental question!
suppose I am going to solve a problem using tensorflow.
i wrote 10 different functions in that code, and each function returns numpy array, that means, each function uses placeholders and with tf.Session() as sess:.
now the questions are,

```
1) how many graphs will be generated.
2) is it a good programming practice?
```

> **Note: before i was using tf.constant in place of tf.placeholder, since the data is huge the tensorflow was showing the following error:
>   "valueerror: graphdef cannot be larger than 2gb"

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It will just be a single tensorflow graph but it will be disconnected. A better programming practice would be to have a connected graph that can compute all ten functions without having to call `sess.run` ten times.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the "valueerror: graphdef cannot be larger than 2gb" error. Therefore a single session will load the whole data set and becomes more that 2gb. correct me if  I am wrong!

Comment: Well that's why you should use placeholders instead of constants.

Comment: but if in that case, if write everything in a single session, on that session all the data i used will be loaded and the graph will be more than 2GB. Am I write? That is why i split it into functions and sessions. I am really confused.my problem is solved but i want to understand the inner picture!!

Comment: I don't think the size of the data counts as part of the size of the graph. I could be wrong about that. It only counts when you make it a constant.